# Is it good idea to provide cache as service?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, scalability, couchbase

We have many web services and web app applications which have caching needs so we are trying to come up with caching strategy which can help all the teams irrespective of their technical choices. We have used Memcached(not replicated) & Couchbase(multi master) running locally on each server node and applications connect to them locally using Memcached protocol but going forward we are planning to go with centralized cache cluster exposed via REST APIs which can be used by all the applications running on different server nodes in a datacenter. Following are reasons behind this thought process:

1. Easy maintenance of a cluster without worrying about app server
   nodes.
2. Single protocol(HTTP) used to access the cache without worrying
   about underlying implementation.(We might use Redis or Couchbase or
   Aerospike cluster)

But we are not sure about this strategy because we are worried about performance impact due to network overhead because of HTTP.

Has anyone tried this strategy? Is it a good idea to make cache as centralized service or local caches are the best?

Answer (score 6):

While it's true that HTTP and network add latency, generally you need a cache because the actual operation takes significantly longer. So the question is: if you add 1-2 milliseconds to the cache access, does that still shorten the un-cached operation time significantly? If the answer is yes, and you follow some common best practices, having a centralized cache could be a good idea.

You might want to look into low latency, high throughput server-side frameworks for the HTTP service, like Node.js or Go. Also, you will probably benefit from implementing proper [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) support in your cache HTTP API.

Another alternative might be centralizing the cache server(s) without wrapping them in an HTTP layer. There are standard cache provider implementations for all the technologies you mentioned available for most modern web frameworks.

Comment: David, do you mean to say if I ditch HTTP and use their proprietary protocol to connect to remote cluster, it will give better performance?

Comment: The increased performance is not necessarily related to the protocol being used (though typically binary protocols (such as Memcached) provide smaller overhead and quicker processing times than text-based ones -- but rather because you're eliminating the middleman - the HTTP gateway - which typically runs in a different process and communicates over some kind of socket/IPC to the actual cache.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**: I work for Redis Labs, a commercial company that makes tools for managing Redis and Memcached clusters. My employer, Redis Labs, has made a business of the strategy that you want affirmed :)

Cache is a dish best served close, but remote caching has benefits (e.g., offloading the DB) even if the latency penalty suggests differently. In most cases, compared to the time spent in the application, the local area network latency becomes negligible, so using a shared network-attached cache makes a lot of sense.

To get the best performance, interact from your app directly with the shared cache using its own protocol. An HTTP API, unless provided by the caching engine itself, could add latency to the client app's requests. OTOH, formalizing your apps access to the cache with a custom layer (such as a REST API) has a lot of nice benefits too, so you should evaluate the cost in the context of your latency budgets.

Your strategy is sound and it is used everywhere to build scalable and performant applications. Feel free to hit me if you need further advice.